# jQuery draggable - multiple snap (to) objects with different snapMode for each object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Situation as follows - one draggable div, can snap to multiple other divs. What I need to achieve - specify different snap modes for different divs. For example - snap:'#firstDiv', snapMode:'inner' and for that same draggable div another snap:'#secondDiv', snapMode:'outer'

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="first" class="tile"><p>first</p></div>
    <div id="second" class="tile"><p>second</p></div>
    <div id="third"><p>3</p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper { 
    width:100%; 
    height:400px; 
    position:relative; 
}
#first, #second, #third { 
    position:absolute; 
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    border:1px solid #000; 
    text-align:center;
}
#first { top:10px; left:10px; }
#second { right:100px; bottom:100px; }

#third {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    left:50px;
    top:150px;
}
p { margin:10px; padding:0px; font-weight:bold; }
```

**JS, with basic snap to something:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#third").draggable({
        containment: '.wrapper',
        cursor: 'move',
        snap: '.tile',
        snapMode: 'outer'
    });     
});
```

Here is jsFiddle with above code: http://jsfiddle.net/563UZ/1/

Comment: any luck getting an answer to this? i also need to snap to mulitple elements in both inner and outer modes.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been trying to get this sort of functionality out of jQuery UI's `snapMode`. Here is a work-around that <s>*sort of*</s> does the trick:

You can change the draggable's `snapMode` for a particular div by turning it into a `droppable`. When the draggable is dragged `over` the droppable, you change it's snapMode `option` from `outer` to `inner`, and then when it's dragged `out` (and the droppable is no longer active), you change it back.

Here are my edits to your fiddle:
<s>http://jsfiddle.net/coffeeCola/563UZ/31/</s>
http://jsfiddle.net/coffeeCola/563UZ/43/

<s>Unfortunately, when the droppable is set to `tolerance: 'touch'` the whole thing sort of wigs out. Setting it to `tolerance: pointer` creates the desired behavior, but the draggable will still snap to the outside of the div before the options are changed.</s>
**[Update]**
I was able to remove the unwanted behavior described above by turning the droppable into the parent of the element and added a margin/padding that is slightly larger than the draggables snapTolerance.